# Condo hazard insurance -- who takes the next step? Everyone else is refusing

Tags: mortgage, banking, insurance, home-owners-association

I live in California.  The bank (in Atlanta) who has our home loan needs to see proof of our condo master hazard insurance policy or they will buy us a policy.

The agent who sold the policy told me it's the bank's responsibility to look this information up on line at icerts.com. The bank claims they can’t/don’t have the capability to go to the website; the insurance agent says, yes, the bank does have the capability and I, the unit owner, am somehow supposed to compel them to do it.  My HOA insists “Either the bank or the insurance agent should get the information.  That’s their job.”

I'm trying to register myself at icerts.  Slow going. Meanwhile I'm asking bank, HOA, insurance agency, for help and suggestions.  My emails go unanswered.  Each continues to point fingers at the other and say "That's HIS job!  Don't you do it, homeowner!  It's not your job!"  Even though my money is going to pay for the new policy if things don't work out.

The whole thing is bizarre and I'm starting to wonder if I need to talk to a lawyer.

Does anyone have suggestions?  Am I doing the right thing by registering at icerts?  If not, what should I do?  TYIA!

Comment: Contact the insurance company directly? But you _should_ have a copy of the policy in your own files, with all the details and the policy number; why is that not enough to satisfy the bank?

Comment: I echo Keshlam's comment. The insurance agent for the condo's master policy should easily be able to provide you with a copy of the policy. I think generally only an early page is actually required (lists policy number, insurer, insured location, and limits). And you should definitely be able to have this document for your records. It is odd that the insurance agent is refusing to provide you with the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

The bank doesn't *have to* do anything. It is your responsibility to provide the proof of insurance. It is the agent's *job*, which you through your HOA dues paid for, to provide that proof to you.

You shouldn't be registering with icerts. They say so in the first sentence on the registration page:

> Unit Owners, Do Not Register Here! If you own an existing property,
>   and have received a letter from your lender requiring an annual
>   renewal/updated certificate for an association that has recently
>   expired, please forward that letter to info@iCerts.com to receive
>   instructions to place your order. If your request is a new loan of any
>   kind, please contact your lender and request that they either contact
>   us to place this order, or register below.

So you can try that route (sending an email to info@icerts.com), and see if it works. It does cost money, in the range of $20-$100 (I used a different similar service at the time and they charged $75 for this).

If it doesn't, you can try and work with the insurance agent. There are some ways to persuade them:

- California has very strong traditions of consumer protections. In this case, I suggest checking out [this site](http://www.insurance.ca.gov/01-consumers/101-help/ConsumerTechTips.cfm). Let the insurance agent know that as the HOA member - they're working **for you**, and that in the next HOA meeting you will raise a request to change the insurance agency. Also, remind the agent that the CA Insurance Commission will knock on their doors to ask why they don't provide you with the proof you need.
- If the HOA management company doesn't help you, you can remind them that they too can be fired. This can be done, and isn't even all that hard. There's a lot of competition in the HOA management market, and it wouldn't be too hard to find a new management company. The HOA management company should have provided you the proof of coverage when they renewed the policy.